# SQL: последний день предыдущего месяца в формате по умолчанию

Tags: sql

Вопрос из [тренажера](https://sql-validator.ru/task/last_months_day).

Напишите запрос, который выводит последний день предыдущего месяца в формате по умолчанию. В выборке должен присутствовать один атрибут: `date`.

Важно! В тренажере не работает функция `current_date`. Например, вы можете использовать 'now' в качестве параметра функции `DATE()`.
Под форматом по умолчанию понимается формат, в котором функции `DATE()`, `TIME()` и `DATETIME()` выводят дату и время соответственно.

Например, такой запрос

```
SELECT DATE(DATE('now'),  '- 1 days') as date;
```

или

```
SELECT DATE(DATE('now'),  '- 1 days');
```

выдает `NULL`.

Comment: Что там хоть за диалект-то? а то во многих имеется соответствующая функция.

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то там SQL странный. А вообще путем решения может быть вариант когда из текущей даты получаем месяц и год, а число берем 1. И собираем дату первого числа текущего месяца.

Дальше из этого вычитаем один день и получаем последнюю дату предыдущего месяца.

Comment: Возможности тренажера ограничены

Answer (score 0):

был лишний пробел в '- 1 days', теперь работает:
SELECT DATE(DATE('now'),  '-1 days') as date;

Answer (score 0):

у меня так получилось вывести дату

```
SELECT DATE(DATE('now'), 'start of month', '-1 days') AS date
```